# OpenCV: camera failed to properly initialize

Tags: python, opencv

I am using below code to Connect to Camera in Spyder. I am able to connect also .
After run the code,It shows pop up to allow , by mistake i pressed Don't allow. Now i am getting below error .

```
import cv2,time

vedio = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

time.sleep(3)
vedio.release()
```

Errror :

> OpenCV: error in [AVCaptureDeviceInput initWithDevice:error:]
>   2019-05-08 11:41:03.192 python[2380:28685] OpenCV: Cannot use FaceTime
>   HD Camera (Built-in) OpenCV: camera failed to properly initialize!

I already restart computer and Anaconda .